# Intent Intents.Insert.ACTION only works the first time?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-notifications

My Android service creates a notification with a custom button. The action for the custom button should open the "Create contact" system screen, with the phone number prefilled. This is the code:

```
// create the base notification
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
    context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(text)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// add the action to save to contacts
Intent saveIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
saveIntent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
saveIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, text);
saveIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
PendingIntent pendingSaveIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, saveIntent, 0);
builder.addAction(0, "Save to Contacts", pendingSaveIntent);

// show the notification
context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE).notify(0, builder.build());
```

The code works well the first time (let's say that I pass "01234-1234567" to it). However, subsequent calls keep showing the same dialog shown the first time, with the same value in it. So even if I call this piece code again with a different number in input (the value of "text" for the "Intents.Insert.PHONE" extra value) I'll always get "01234-1234567".

I tried cancelling the Contacts screen, manually create a new contact, completely stopping the Contacts apps...no matter what, next time I tap on the notification's button I'll get the screen with the value I originally passed on the first attempt.

Do you have any explanation or see anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Basically, the system caches intents, unless they differ for something more than just the extra params. In my code I was only changing the phone number, so it was always using the same (first) cached intent. The solution is to use a flag to cancel the currently cached intent and create a new one

```
PendingIntent pendingSaveIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0, saveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The system cashes intents, so in your PendingIntent instead of typing 0 as flag, use (PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), try this:

PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, saveIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);